# Array length in Pascal

Tags: arrays, pascal

I don't know how does the array range really limit me, for example this program

```
program Test;
  var
    a:integer;
    c:array[1..5] of integer;
  begin
    for a:=0 to 8 do begin
      read(c[a]);
    end;
    for a:=0 to 8 do begin
      writeln(c[a]);
    end;
end.
```

for input 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 writes 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (all in a new row because of writeln) but array range should be from 1 to 5, how does it accept more values then? I also tried with Setlength(c,5) but same story

Comment: Since you're using a variable for index, the compiler is unable to check.

Comment: so what should I do then?

Comment: I thought you were asking why were the compiler not complaining when you access the 0'th element. If that's correct, hopefully turning on range checking will catch it at run time. There's nothing to do at compile time.

Comment: If you turn on range checking, the code will generate a range check exception (ERangeError, IIRC) at runtime if you exceed the bounds of the array. You should always have it enabled during development to catch errors like this one.

Comment: you should reindent your code

Answer (score 3):

```
  for a:=low(c) to high(c) do
   <code>
```

Newer delphi's might also allow length, defined as high(c)-low(c)+1

Comment: Is this available is turbo pascal?

Comment: I don't know if it is in all versions (specially the very old ones available from museum sites), but TP3 and later have it.